# Table view cell with label and textField and equal space between each other

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, uitextfield

i want to create a table view with cells which have a textField.
What drives me crazy is the spacing between label and textField cause i want a equal spacing in all cells.

To better explain take a look at this screenshot.

[image: Example UI]

So im searching for a good way to get the spacing between *Second Label* and *Second textField* and set this on the other cells, too.

Is there a way to do it in the storyboard and not by edit the constraint in code?

Comment: Please include a [example] what you have already tried and a picture of the required layout.

Comment: Did you set the trailing space of the label to the textField?

Comment: Of course, but that's not the solution to have the same width for label and textField in all my cells based on the largest label

Comment: Pre-calculate the width of all the labels and store the largest value. Then use that inside your cells to set the leading constraint for the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that:

1. use a horizontal stackview to hold the label and textField with some spacing in between, like 10.
2. set the label's width constraint to a fixed value.

the details are as follows:

1. add a horizontal stackview into the cell's contentView
2. set the stackview constraints to fill the contentView with some margins:
   eg. leading: 20, trailing 20, top 10, bottom 10.
3. add a label and a textField into the stackview.
4. in the stackview's Attribute inspector, set the spacing to 10.
5. set the label's width constraint to 100, or 0.3:1 to the contentView's width

so the label will have a fixed width, fixed spacing between label and textField, and the textField will take all the horizontal space remain.

Comment: I don't want fixed values for width of label or textField, it should be all dynamic. To key question is how i can set a trailing space from textField to the label and share this with the other cells so that the ui looks like in the image in my question.

Comment: is there a rule for this dynamic value you want? In my answer, the fixed value can be varied by the width of the screen, and reproduce the table as the picture in your question... you can even set the label’s width to a ratio of the textField’s...